# How can references to private class members be dangerouse

Tags: java, security, oop, member

I am currently reading the [CERT Secure Coding Standard for Java](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/SEI+CERT+Oracle+Coding+Standard+for+Java).

I am struggling with this [rule](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/OBJ05-J.+Do+not+return+references+to+private+mutable+class+members). The severity of this rule is high, which means a violation of this rule can lead to a privilege escalation or execution of code.

I don't really understand how a violation of this rule can lead to such fatal things. Can somebody make an example of an attack on a code which violates this rule?

Comment: There are already examples on the page you linked to. What's wrong with those?

Comment: If you expose reference to the private mutable object, like `Date` or any modifiable `Collection`, you can modify the state of your object from outside. Imagine you have `List<String> getNames()` method, you can call it and then call `add("name")`. So the person who use your class can modify internal state of the instance. See also J. **Bloch's "Effective Java" 2nd edition, Item 39, p. 184**

Comment: non of the examples are leading to a code execution or a privilege escalation or am I wrong?

Comment: @Exagon those are not the risks stated in the article: "Returning references to internal object state (mutable or immutable) can render an application susceptible to information leaks and corruption of its objects' states, which consequently violates class invariants. Control flow can also be affected in some cases.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have an invariant which you establish in the constructor of the class, e.g. that `date` contains the creation time of the instance:

```
class Foo {
  private final Date date;

  Foo() { this.date = new Date(); }

  Date getDate() { return date; }
}
```

Now, if I call `getDate().setTime(0)`, I can make the instance look like it was created at `1970-1-1 00:00:00Z`.

If you have some logic based on the creation date of a `Foo`, it can be manipulated to behave differently in this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you expose reference to the private mutable object (for example `Date` or any modifiable `Collection`) over the getter, you can modify the state of your object from outside.

Imagine you have `List<String> getNames()` method in your class:

```
public class MyClass {
    // fields and constructors are omitted
    List<String> getNames() {
        // return any mutable List implementation; for instance, ArrayList
    }
}
```

You can call `myClass.getNames().add("name")`, and this will modify the state of the `MyClass` instance. So the person who use your class can modify internal state of its instances.

See also **J. Bloch's "Effective Java" 2nd edition, Item 39 "Make defensive copies when needed", p. 184**, you can find very good explanation on this tiopic there.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you are circumventing the `private` specifier by having a non-`private` function that returns a reference to the member.

That's because it's possible to modify the the object to which the member is referring through that reference.

You may as well be honest about things, and mark the `private` member with the same access specifier as the function.