# Why can private members in Java be modified from another class?

Tags: java, oop

In the following example, `x` can be changed by class `B` even though it's a private member of class `A`. What's the reason for this?

```
import java.util.Date;

class A {

    private Date x;

    public A(){
        super();
        x = new Date();
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        return x;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }

}

class B {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    A a = new A();

    a.print();

    Date d = a.getDate();

    d.setMonth(12);

    System.out.println(d);

    a.print();

    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Initial date generated by A
Date changed by B
Date changed by B (why does it change a private member here?)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private)

Comment: I don't see how that output is generated from this code.

Comment: Don't confuse variables, scope (compile time), and objects (runtime).

Comment: That's not the output. It's also perfectly valid to get and set private variables from a method. You just can't access them directly.

Comment: Higly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375990/how-can-references-to-private-class-members-be-dangerouse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`private` prevents a variable from being accessed **directly** by another class. You cannot write `d.x` to read or write to `x`.

If the class chooses to return a reference to `x` via a public method, though, that's it's own choice to pierce the veil of privacy. Nothing stops `A` from allowing `x` to be read from a getter or modified from a setter.

In recent years the Java community has recognized the problem with this: namely, if you return a reference to a private mutable object, you open the door for your class's internal state to be mucked with without its knowledge. To protect against this, it has become good practice to make classes **immutable** whenever possible.

Indeed, `Date` is a perfect example of a poorly-designed mutable class. The `java.time` package introduced in Java 8 added a slew of immutable time and date classes to replace `Date`. You can now return a private [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and not worry about callers being able to change it.

It's important to point out that immutability comes from how a class is defined. It's not a language-level feature like `private`. Confusingly, `final` can be used to make variables immutable, but applying it to a class does not make the class immutable (it makes it unextendable).

Comment: `to pierce the veil of privacy` deserves an upvote in and of itself. Also, the real confusion here is that the getter doesn't return a copy, or that private would somehow make the object immutable outside of its class

Answer (score 3):

You're not changing the private property.  Try this and see it fail:

```
A a = new A();
a.x = someOtherValue;
```

But the `A` class does allow you to *read* the property:

```
public Date getDate(){
    return x;
}
```

And the `Date` class allows you to set *its* property:

```
d.setMonth(12);
```

No `private` member is being accessed outside of a class here.  `Date` and `A` are two different classes.

Answer (score 1):

This did not change `x` it is still pointing to the same object. What was changed is the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing *reference* with *value*.

The `Date` object referred to by `x` never changes and the field `x` is inaccessible from the sub class - ie the sub class can't assign a different `Date` object to `x`.

However, the getter allows you to access the object referred to by `x`, and (perhaps unexpectedly) `Date` objects are *mutable* - that is a `Date`'s *value* can be changed. It's still the same `Date` object, but the instant in time it represents is different.

---

IMHO, the `Date` class is "broken"; it should be [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Answer (score 0):

The `getDate()` method is public. The getter method is public, that is you can now access the object and change its value. `Date d` and `Date x` are only reference to those objects not the actual objects.